# How to Pass a Workspace Path to the Quarkus Native Build Task in a VS Code Dev Container

Tags: quarkus, vscode-devcontainer

I am using the VS Code Dev Container with the "docker-outside-of-docker" feature to develop a new Quarkus project. The Maven build is functioning as expected.

Now, I would like to use Docker to build a native executable. I am running the following command:

```
./mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
```

Docker is running outside of the dev container, as configured via the "docker-outside-of-docker" setting.

The image "quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image" was pulled, but the process fails when running the container with an `Invalid Path entry` error. Docker is unable to recognize the internal path.

```
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildRunner] docker run --env LANG=C --rm --user 1000:1000 -v /workspaces/hello-quarkus/target/hello-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar:/project:z --name build-native-hINyv ...

Error: Invalid Path entry hello-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
```

Within the dev container, I have set the actual workspace path in an environment variable:

```
LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER=/user/pinei/projects/hello-quarkus
```

My question is: How can I pass the LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER path to the quarkus.native.container-build task?